# Will a request to api.myapp.com be slower then a request to api-myapp.herokuapp.com when hosted on heroku?

Tags: http, networking, heroku, soa

I'm trying to understand the best way to handle SOA on heroku, i've got it into my head that making requests to custom domains will somehow be slower, or would all requests go "out" via the internet?

On previous projects which are SOA in nature we've had dedicated hosting so could make requests like `http://blogs/` (obviously on the internal network) I'm wondering if heroku treats `*.herokuapp.com` requests as "internal"... Or is it clever enough to know the `myapp.com` is actually `myapp.herokuapp.com` and route locally, or am i missing the point completely, and in fact all requests are "external"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking about is general knowledge of how internet requests are working.

Whenever you do request from your application to lets say `example.com`, domain name will first be translated into IP address using so called DNS servers.

So this how it works: does not matter you request myapp.com or myapp.heroku.com you will always request infromation from specific IP address, and domain name you have requested will be passed as part of request headers.
Server which receives this request will try to find in its internal records this domain name and handle request accordingly.

So conclusion is that *does not matter you put myapp.com or myapp.heroku.com, the speed of request will always be same*.

PS: As heroku will load balance your requests between different instances of your running myapp.com, the speed here will depend on several factors: how quickly your application will respond, how many instances you have running and load average per instance, how much is load balancer loaded at the moment. But surely it will not depend on which domain name you use.

Comment: i was starting to wonder this, so in theory, the request would be as fast as any ec2 > ec2 request in the same zone?

Comment: If the request is sent from the heroku servers, it will not leave that network, because there will be a nameserver which will find the URL you are requesting (for `*.heroku.com`). But in order to resolve `myapp.net` it will try to find it outside the network, if the DNS for the URL is not the network.

Comment: Awesome thanks guys, i think i was thrown by some of heroku's "layers" in particular the "routing mesh" was confusing me.

Comment: @craigtmackenzie Please remember about network latency. Everything that happens within one network will be fast enough, if you need to cross half of globe then there is geo latency. This is why we did not go for heroku, but have our private infrastructure on AWS EC2, just because then we have control over where our servers are located. And hence can use latency based load balancing.

Comment: But if all components of this app are hosted on ec2, within the same region (zone?) then latency should be consistent and minimal (caveats aside), correct? It would only be if api2.myapp.com were half way across the globe on another network that there would be an issue?

Comment: I am not sure about your specific conditions. Are you talking about requests from service consumer to service provider in your SOA? If yes, then problem with heroku is that you cannot be sure that all instances are running in the same region or same sub-netowrk. Of course it is all running within AWS (since heroku is built on top of it), but there are many data centers in AWS. In each zone you will see sub-networks like us-east-1a, us-east-1b etc. So in case if your instances are from same sub-network, then all fine, you will have minimum delay.

Comment: On the other hand advantage (in our case) of using AWS directly, but not heroku is because AWS provides internal networking solutions where you use local (internal) addresses which are being routed within AWS (you can group all your instances into your own private network with minimum latency there). As far as i can recall it Heroku do not have this, so requests there possibly will be routed using outside nodes.